# MIPS reading and storing bytes

Tags: mips

So , I have an assignement where I need to read a 12-bit codeword and detect the error with hamming code.I want to read every bit seperately as a character and then convert it to a bit and store it so I can use it later...From the pseudocode given I guess I have to somehow store it on "CodeWord" or something like that..I still dont quite understand this...Here is what I tried...I store my bit counter on $s0 and $t0 is my base_register...Here is the pseudocode as well(the data section was given like this from the teachers )...I couldn't figure out how to add some of the text in a code box...sorry

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Read CodeWord [data+parity bits (12 digits 0 or 1)] from input
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# $t0 = base register of array CodeWord[]

# counter = 0

# while (counter < 12)

#   Read one char ('0' or '1') from input
#   convert char to digit
#   Store digit (0 or 1) to CodeWord
#   calculate next potition of array CodeWord[]
#   counter ++

# end of while

# for example: input in CodeWord -> 1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1
```

```
.data

CodeWord:       .byte 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

    .text
    .globl main
    
main:

    la $t0,CodeWord
    move $s0,$zero
        
loop:

    bge $s0,12,exit_loop
    li $v0,12
    syscall
    addi $v0,$v0,-48
    sb $v0,Codeword($t0)
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    addi $s0,$s0,1
    j loop
```

Comment: `sb $v0,Codeword($t0)` is incorrect, since `$t0` already contains the address of `CodeWord`. Just do `sb $v0,($t0`

Comment: However, the pseudo-code is not sufficiently clear in my opinion. Nowhere does it say that you're supposed to use one byte per digit. For all we know they could expect you to pack the bits together. Or maybe you're allowed to store them any which way you want. You might want to ask your teacher to clarify that.

Comment: It works.Thank you very much!